# Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::__construct()

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to implement Laravel passport for two tables, so one would be default User and second one would be for Devices.
I created in the config the Guard for the new model and if I try to register the devices its writing to the Device table everything but, right now if I try to login it gives me this error:

```
 Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::__construct() must implement interface Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider, null given, called in /Users/petarceho/laravel/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/AuthManager.php on line 127 in file /Users/petarceho/laravel/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/SessionGuard.php on line 99
```

I'm new to Laravel so sorry for not able to explain it well, but can I use Laravel passport for two tables.

Here is my Controller class for Devices :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Device;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class DeviceController extends Controller{

    //register
    public function signupDevice(Request $request)
    {

        //cant registed with the same email twice
        if(sizeof(Device::where('name','=',$request->query('name'))->get()) > 0)
            return response()->json(['name has already been taken'],500);



        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required|string',
            'password' => 'required|string|confirmed']);

        $device =new Device(
            [

                'name'=>$request->name,
                'password'=>bcrypt($request->password)

            ]);
        $device->save();
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Successfully created device!'
        ], 201);
    }

    public function login(Request $request)
    {

      if (Auth::guard('device')->attempt(['name' => request(['name']), 'password' => request(['password'])])) {
          $details = Auth::guard('device')->user();
            $user = $details['original'];
            return $user;}
      else {return 'auth fail';}

    }

    public function login1(Request $request){

        //validate the data input
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required|string', // |string|name
            'password' => 'required|string',
            //  'remember_me' => 'boolean'
        ]);

        $credentials = request(['name', 'password']);
        if(!Auth::attempt($credentials))
            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'Unauthorized'
            ], 401);


        $device = $request->user('device');
        //  $device = Auth::guard('device')->device();


        $tokenResult = $device->createToken('Personal Access Token');
        $token = $tokenResult->token;
        if ($request->remember_me)
            $token->expires_at = Carbon::now()->addWeeks(1);
        $token->save();

        return response()->json([
            'access_token' => $tokenResult->accessToken,
            'token_type' => 'Bearer',
            'expires_at' => Carbon::parse(
                $tokenResult->token->expires_at
            )->toDateTimeString()
        ],200);
    }





}
```

Here is my config `auth.php` file.

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Defaults
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default authentication "guard" and password
    | reset options for your application. You may change these defaults
    | as required, but they're a perfect start for most applications.
    |
    */

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],


    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Guards
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Next, you may define every authentication guard for your application.
    | Of course, a great default configuration has been defined for you
    | here which uses session storage and the Eloquent user provider.
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | Supported: "session", "token"
    |
    */

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],

        'device'=>
            [
                'driver'=>'session',
               // 'model'=>App\Device::class,
                'provider'=>'devices',
            ],
                ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | User Providers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
    | sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
    | be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
    |
    | Supported: "database", "eloquent"
    |
    */

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],

        'devices' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Device::class,
        ],
                     ],
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Resetting Passwords
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may specify multiple password reset configurations if you have more
    | than one user table or model in the application and you want to have
    | separate password reset settings based on the specific user types.
    |
    | The expire time is the number of minutes that the reset token should be
    | considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
    | they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
    |
    */

    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
    ],

];
```

and my routes:

```
//routes for device auth
Route::group(
    [
        'prefix'=>'auth/device'
    ],function ()
    {
        Route::post('signup','DeviceController@signupDevice');
        Route::post('login','DeviceController@login');
    });
```

the App/Device class

the Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Device looks exactly like User class

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Device as Authenticatable;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;

class Device extends Authenticatable{


    use Notifiable;//,HasApiTokens;



    protected $table ='device';


   protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'password',
    ];
    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];


}
```

Any idea how to use Laravel passport for Multi auth authentication for two tables ?

Comment: Please edit the question and add the `App\Device` model

Comment: About your last question: Before I had similar question and nothinh helped me, so I've used JWT for that

Comment: You should be getting the `EloquentUserProvider` with that configuration. Have you tried running `php artisan config:clear`?

Comment: Adam this solved this ,i'm getting right now different errors but this one is cleared ,thank you !